# How to debug with visual studio code a mocha test in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, visual-studio-code

If you are using node, it is easy to debug:

```
//.vscode/launch.json
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        ...
```

But if I am using mocha tests, how can I debug it?

I have tried to use:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch",
        "type": "mocha",
        "request": "launch",
```

But it is not valid. Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create this new debug target in .vscode/launch.json

   ```
   {
       "name": "Unit tests",
       "type": "node",
       "program": "${workspaceRoot}/mocha.js",
       "stopOnEntry": true,
       "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/TESTTODEBUG.js"],
       "runtimeExecutable": null,
       "env": {
           "NODE_ENV": "test"
        }
   ```
2. Create the file mocha.js

   ```
   'use strict';

   // Dependencies
   var Mocha = require('mocha');

   // Determine which tests to run based on argument passed to runner
   var args = process.argv.splice(2);
   //var args = ["./tests/unit/services/supra-statement.service.test.js"];
   var files;



   //Define Mocha
   var mocha = new Mocha({
     timeout: 60000,
     reporter: 'spec',
     globals: ['Associations', 'CREATE_TEST_WATERLINE', 'DELETE_TEST_WATERLINE']
   });

   args.forEach(mocha.addFile.bind(mocha));

   //Run unit tests
   mocha.run(function (failures) {
       process.exit(failures);
   });
   ```
3. Run the debugger with the Unit test Option